# How to stop all C# Tasks safely running inside a Thread in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am having a C# thread which is running repeatedly  after 10  minutes and from this thread suppose 10 C# 4.0 tasks are running for different amount of time doing some work.

Now when I am repeating the thread how can I ensure that all the 10 inner tasks gets stopped safely and then start again once this thread gets start running again.

Comment: Show your code please. If you are using `Task` class, you can call `Wait()` method on task objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wait until some `Task`s complete, you could store them somewhere and then call [`Task.WaitAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx).

But it's hard to say if this is the best approach without knowing more about your code.

Comment: my tasks wont get completed any time because they are infinite

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Why? `Task`s work better if you use them to perform the work you need and then finish them (by returning from the delegate).